# Are TTL to USB converters bi-directional?

Tags: usb, converter, ttl

I'm trying to convert 5V TTL signals into USB signals that a PC can read. However, most converters that I'm able to find are defined as USB-TTL converters. Can I convert TTL signals to USB signals using a USB-TTL converter?

This is the converter that I was looking at: https://sg.element14.com/ftdi/ttl-232r-5v-we/cable-usb-ttl-ser-conv-5v-wire/dp/1740364

Comment: "I'm trying to convert 5V TTL signals into USB signals that a PC can read." - Could you elaborate what you mean by this? What signals, what do they do, and what is the PC doing with them (i.e. how does it "read" them).

Comment: I am trying to read from a sensor that is constantly pushing out serial TTL data. The end goal that I have in mind is for me to plug this sensor into a PC and have the PC read from this sensor automatically.

Comment: Yes, they are bidirectional. Look at the data sheet you linked to and it shows that you have access to transmit and receive data.

Answer (score 2):

A converter is a misleading term. They are not converters.
They are USB UART ICs, which means they provide a full UART over an USB interface. And that cable simply integrates a USB UART IC.

So yes, it can be used to receive 5V TTL UART data.